# How to create chain index USING dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with department, category, year and sales. See the sample table below:

**Table name: ABC**

| department | category | year | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | 1 | 2012 | 20 |
| HR | 1 | 2012 | 30 |
| Marketing | 1 | 2012 | 60 |
| Finance | 2 | 2012 | 50 |
| HR | 2 | 2012 | 15 |
| Marketing | 2 | 2012 | 17 |
| Finance | 1 | 2013 | 60 |
| HR | 1 | 2013 | 40 |
| Marketing | 1 | 2013 | 90 |
| Finance | 2 | 2013 | 7 |
| HR | 2 | 2013 | 20 |
| Marketing | 2 | 2013 | 22 |
| Finance | 1 | 2014 | 50 |
| HR | 1 | 2014 | 39 |
| Marketing | 1 | 2014 | 120 |

Using the DAX query language, I was able to create the relative index

| department | category | year | sales | relative_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | 1 | 2012 | 20 | 100 |
| HR | 1 | 2012 | 30 | 100 |
| Marketing | 1 | 2012 | 60 | 100 |
| Finance | 2 | 2012 | 50 | 100 |
| HR | 2 | 2012 | 15 | 100 |
| Marketing | 2 | 2012 | 17 | 100 |
| Finance | 1 | 2013 | 60 | `(60/20)*100 = 300` |
| HR | 1 | 2013 | 40 | `(40/30)*100 = 133` |
| Marketing | 1 | 2013 | 90 | `(90/60)*100 = 150` |
| Finance | 2 | 2013 | 7 | `(7/50)*100 = 14` |
| HR | 2 | 2013 | 20 | `(20/15)*100 = 133` |
| Marketing | 2 | 2013 | 22 | `(22/17)*100 = 129` |
| Finance | 1 | 2014 | 50 | `(50/60)*100 = 83` |
| HR | 1 | 2014 | 39 | `(39/40)*100 = 97.5` |
| Marketing | 1 | 2014 | 120 | `(120/90)*100 = 133` |

I used the following dax code to create the relatie_index

```
Relative_Link = 
//Inception = get the minimum year
var Inception = MIN(ABC[year])
//FY_LY = get the previous year
var FY_LY = ABC[year]-1
//LY_level = get the previous year's sales for a department and category 
previous year
var LY_level = calculate(sum(ABC[sales]), filter(allexcept(ABC, ABC[department], 
ABC[category]), ABC[year]=FY_LY))

return if(ABC[year]=Inception, 100, (ABC[sales]/LY_level)*100)
```

I am having trouble creating the chain_index column

| department | category | year | sales | relative_index | chain_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | 1 | 2012 | 20 | 100 | 100 |
| HR | 1 | 2012 | 30 | 100 | 100 |
| Marketing | 1 | 2012 | 60 | 100 | 100 |
| Finance | 2 | 2012 | 50 | 100 | 100 |
| HR | 2 | 2012 | 15 | 100 | 100 |
| Marketing | 2 | 2012 | 17 | 100 | 100 |
| Finance | 1 | 2013 | 60 | `(60/20)*100 = 300` | `(100*300)/100 = 300` |
| HR | 1 | 2013 | 40 | `(40/30)*100 = 133` | `(100*133)/100 = 133` |
| Marketing | 1 | 2013 | 90 | `(90/60)*100 = 150` | `(100*150)/100 = 150` |
| Finance | 2 | 2013 | 7 | `(7/50)*100 = 14` | `(100*14)/100 = 14` |
| HR | 2 | 2013 | 20 | `(20/15)*100 = 133` | `(100*133)/100 = 133` |
| Marketing | 2 | 2013 | 22 | `(22/17)*100 = 129` | `(100*129)/100 = 129` |
| Finance | 1 | 2014 | 50 | `(50/60)*100 = 83` | `(83*300)/100 = 249` |
| HR | 1 | 2014 | 39 | `(39/40)*100 = 97.5` | `(97.5*133)/100 = 130` |
| Marketing | 1 | 2014 | 120 | `(120/90)*100 = 133` | `(133*150)/100 = 199.5` |

I am trying to use the following formula:

```
Chain_Index = 
//Inception = get the min year
var Inception = MIN(ABC[year])
//FY_LY = get the previous year
var FY_LY = ABC[year]-1
//Next_Year = Inception + 1
var next_year = Inception + 1
//LY_ChainIndex_Value = get the previous chain index value from previous year
var LY_ChainIndex_Value = calculate(sum(ABC[chain_index]), filter(allexcept(ABC, 
ABC[department], ABC[category]), ABC[FY_CY]=FY_LY))
return if(ABC[FY_CY]=Inception, 100, (ABC[relative_index]*LY_ChainIndex_Value)/100)
```

I am getting the following error message:

`A circular dependency was detected: ABC[chain_index].`

I am trying to create chain index value described in this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXzNvxCB0_g&t=234

Thanks for reading and help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quick testing, the following column works great to calculate the chain_index:

```
chain_index = 
VAR _ly = [year] - 1
VAR _ly_index = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( 'ABC'[relative_index] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'ABC' , 'ABC'[department] , 'ABC'[category] ) ,
        'ABC'[year] = _ly 
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        ISBLANK ( _ly_index ) , 
        100 , 
        ( [relative_index] * _ly_index ) / 100 
    )
```

Basing the `relative_index` on the following:

```
relative_index = 
VAR _ly = [year] - 1
VAR _ly_sales = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( 'ABC'[sales] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'ABC' , 'ABC'[department] , 'ABC'[category] ) , 
        'ABC'[year] = _ly 
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        ISBLANK ( _ly_sales ) , 
        100 , 
        100.0 * ( [sales] / _ly_sales ) 
    )
```

I suspect the circular dependency is caused by whatever it is you are doing to calculate this column `'ABC'[FY_CY]` - a column you do not need for this calculation at least.

Unless you are planning to deploy these indexing columns for categorization or slicing, then the best practice is to calculate these values using measures instead of making your data model bigger with calculated columns.